# Set Id for views dynamically created by a for each loop - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I'm adding an unknown number of views to a TableLayout dynamically by iterating over an ArrayList with a for..each loop.

When I try to set unique ids to each view, each view ends up having the same ID.

```
    TableLayout Table = findViewById(R.id.table);    
    idCounter = 0;

    for (String string: array) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        // adds id to table
        TextView serialText = new TextView(this);
        serialText.setText(string);
        row.addView(serialText);
        serialText.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter ++;

        // first checkbox
        CheckBox firstCheckbox= new CheckBox(this);
        row.addView(firstcheckbox);
        firstcheckbox.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter ++;

        firstCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onCheckBoxClick(idCounter);
            }
        });

        // second checkbox
        CheckBox secondCheckbox= new CheckBox(this);
        row.addView(secondCheckbox);
        secondCheckbox.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter ++; 

        secondCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onCheckBoxClick(idCounter);
            }
        });

        // third checkbox
        CheckBox thirdCheckbox= new CheckBox(this);
        row.addView(thirdCheckbox);
        thirdCheckbox.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter ++;

        thirdCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onCheckBoxClick(idCounter);
            }
        });

        // add row to table
        Table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

I need each view to have a unique ID so I can differentiate between the views when an OnClickListener is used.

```
public void onCheckBoxClick(Integer id) {

    Log.d("ID", id);
}
```

Each checkbox has the same ID, it's always the last one that has been set.

Comment: Hod did you know that it ends up having the same id?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had an onClickListener to log the id but removed it for readability. I'll edit it back in

Comment: Use `View.generateViewId()` that will generate unique id for every view. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId())

Comment: You're not checking the ID correctly. `onCheckBoxClick(idCounter);` will end up logging whatever the last value of `idCounter` was. You want to call it with the ID of the clicked `View`; i.e., `onCheckBoxClick(v.getId());`. Also, you generally want to use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` with a `Checkbox`, rather than an `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First [View.generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) (API level > 17) will create an unique id for your view.

Then use [setId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) to set that generated id.

Answer (score 0):

`Other solution`, you can create 1 static variable in a class extends application class, and increase it.

examples:In YourApplication extend Application:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    public static int newId = 1;
}
```

And when want new id, just increase newId.